# how to draw 2 or more routes with googlemapsApi

Tags: android

My app have already implemented the option to draw a route between user location to the point.

Now i need to adapt the code with 5 locations and draw on map between them

My code :

```
public void getRoute(final LatLng origin, final LatLng destination) {

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            int l = 0;
                     l++;

            String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="
                    + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude + "&destination="
                    + destination.latitude + "," + destination.longitude + "&sensor=true&mode=walking&alternatives=true&region=pt";

            HttpResponse response;
            HttpGet request;
            AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("route");

            request = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                response = client.execute(request);
                final String answer = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {

                            list = buildJSONRoute(answer);
                            drawRoute();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}


public List<LatLng> buildJSONRoute(String json) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray routes = result.getJSONArray("routes");




    JSONArray steps = routes.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("steps");

    List<LatLng> lines = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    for (int i = 0; i < steps.length(); i++) {


        String polyline = steps.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("polyline").getString("points");

        for (LatLng p : decodePolyline(polyline)) {
            lines.add(p);
        }

    }

    return (lines);
}


// Line
private List<LatLng> decodePolyline(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> listPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)), (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        Log.i("Script", "POL: LAT: " + p.latitude + " | LNG: " + p.longitude);
        listPoints.add(p);
    }
    return listPoints;
}
```

Draw a route

```
 public void drawRoute() {
        PolylineOptions po;
        if (this.polyline == null) {
            po = new PolylineOptions();
            int i = 0;

            for (int tam = list.size(); i < tam; ++i) {
                po.add(list.get(i));
            }

            po.color(Color.BLACK);
            this.polyline = this.map.addPolyline(po);
        } else {
            this.polyline.setPoints(list);
        }

    }
```

Any suggestion how to adapt the code? 
This code works fine draw a route between user location and point location

I need to do something like this :

[Image](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Handlers/DownloadFile.ashx?File=85b29ec6-999c-4073-af4a-1a0fc321aa7f.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have already set origin and destinations points in your code so what is next is to add waypoints between them. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints) is how to adapt your code to make url with waypoints.

And it seems someone have already implemented for multiple points [here](https://github.com/tato469/Android/tree/master/routes%20googleMaps%20v2).
Related code snippet from the link.

Route.java

```
     private String makeURL (ArrayList<LatLng> points, String mode, boolean optimize){
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();

        if(mode == null)
            mode = "driving";

        urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
        urlString.append("?origin=");// from
        urlString.append( points.get(0).latitude);
        urlString.append(',');
        urlString.append(points.get(0).longitude);
        urlString.append("&destination=");
        urlString.append(points.get(points.size()-1).latitude);
        urlString.append(',');
        urlString.append(points.get(points.size()-1).longitude);

        urlString.append("&waypoints=");
        if(optimize)
         urlString.append("optimize:true|");
        urlString.append( points.get(1).latitude);
        urlString.append(',');
        urlString.append(points.get(1).longitude);

        for(int i=2;i<points.size()-1;i++)
        {
            urlString.append('|');
            urlString.append( points.get(i).latitude);
            urlString.append(',');
            urlString.append(points.get(i).longitude);
        }


        urlString.append("&sensor=true&mode="+mode);


        return urlString.toString();
 }
```